# One word for accepting the punishment or consequence for one's wrong doing

Tags: meaning, terminology

The title is the question and the word starts with a "C". It exactly follows the given definition. I just can't remember the word. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: [OneLook reverse dictionary search](http://onelook.com/?clue=accepting+the+punishment+or+consequence+for+one+wrong+doing&loc=revfp3&w=c*)

Comment: I suppose not *[culpable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/culpable#Adjective)* or *[culpability](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/culpability)*?

Comment: Always include the actual question in the body of the post, even if it appears in the title. The title is **not** the question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Contrite](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/contrite)* is probably the word you seek:-

> 1. caused by or showing sincere remorse.
> 2. filled with a sense of guilt and the desire for atonement; penitent: a contrite sinner.

Comment: Or a cognate of the adjective "contrite," the noun, "contrition."

Answer (score 1):

**concede**

[definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concede): to accept as true, valid, or accurate

**confess**

[definition 1.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confess): to tell or make known.
*He willingly confessed his crime.*

[definition 2.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/confess)  to own or admit as true; concede

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. "Concede" comes close but there is another word which exactly fits the context of my question. It's when somebody has commited a crime and he/she accepts his/her punishment.

Comment: Second attempt see above.

Comment: I second Mari-lou. Pls post the word here when you get it.

Answer (score 0):

Punishment is the consequence of your wrong doing.  Parents tell their children to cease from parties cookouts celebrations until  you gather yourselves together and accept that punishment we will not be forgiven and cleansed from our idols and sin.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You may be looking for

> **cede**

It means "to give over."

Comment: This may look I have downvoted this answer, but I haven't. Although I agree the answer is incomplete and inaccurate.